# R Docker Kubernetes Websocket Closing

Tags: r, docker, kubernetes, shiny, envoyproxy

I have deployed my R shiny app via Kubernetes using an R-Base docker image from Rocker. I am also using the contour HTTP proxy: https://projectcontour.io/docs/master/httpproxy/ .

It seems that the websocket will periodically close even though I set the timeout to infinity as described in the Contour wiki above:

```
timeoutPolicy:
   response: "infinity"
   idle: "infinity"
```

I even instrumented an in-app keep alive mechanism as described below to periodically have JS send a message to R: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/issues/126.

Is there any other reason as to why the websocket would periodically close?
I do not have this issue locally and there are no errors on the console (outside of the websocket close: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null) or on the R side.

Thank you